# To find positive integers from $Z_8$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

> Let $Z_8$ be the set of all congruence classes of integers $\text {modulo} \ 8$. Find positive integers $a,b$ such that $[a][b]=[0]$. ($[a]$ denotes the congruence class of $a$ $\text {modulo}\ 8$

First of all, I have no idea what does $[b]$ denote.

If $$[a][b]=[0]\\ a \mod 8. [b]=[0]$$. But here I am clueless and stuck.

Now if it wants to know for which positive $a,b$, we can represent $a.b\equiv0\mod 8$, as any or both of them are even. Otherwise I don't know how to solve it.

I need help to solve and any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: $[a]$ is the remainder of $a$ on division by $8,$ considered as an element of $\mathbf Z_8.$  For example, $[33]=1\in \mathbf Z_8.$

Comment: As your exercise says, $[b]$ is the congruence class mod $8$ that contains the integer $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example could be $$[a]\equiv 2\pmod 8 \quad\text{and}\quad [b]\equiv 4\pmod 8$$
You are looking for the [zero divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor), and in $\mathbb{Z}_8$ they are the numbers that are not coprime with $8$.

Comment: Is it similar to $a.b\equiv0\mod 8$ ?

Comment: @thevbm if you mean $a\color{red}{\cdot}b\equiv 0\pmod 8$ you are right!

Comment: When we talk about congruences we always deal with infinite number of solutions. In your case all the solution are of the form $[a][b]=8k\quad\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}_8$.

Comment: So for example $8.2=2.8=4.4=[a].[b]$ or $[a][b]=1.8=8.1=2.4=4.2=8.k$ am I correct?

Comment: Yes. But remember that $[8]\equiv [0]\pmod 8$